# Variable changes value unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a JavaScript(jQuery) code that toggles a certain fieldset according to other field value.

### Explained code:

Here is the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jKU9h/ I'm sorry since the HTML is a little bit messy since it's generated using PHP. However, it is still readable.

Declaring global vars:

```
var first = true, // initial value
    dynamic_fieldset, // the value is set in the code below
    form, // selector of the form, the value is okay.
    origin_fixRel; // value for this var is set somewhere in the code, the value is okay.
```

here I bind the change event, and set a global var `first`. The first time I change the select box, it makes a clone of the current fieldset.

```
    $('body').on('change','#efixRel', function() {
        
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if(first) {
            dynamic_fieldset = $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset:last-child').clone(true,true);
            first = false;
        }
```

the var `origin_fixRel` comes from another part of the code, assume the var holds the right value. Here I check if the user has chosen back the option before he changed it. If he did, I remove the current fieldset and append instead the cloned fieldset from before.

```
if(origin_fixRel == $value) {
            form.find('fieldset').eq(1).remove();
            form.find('.formContainer').eq(0).append(dynamic_fieldset);
        } else {
```

If he didn't and he chose another option (for instance, the first case when he changes from the initial value to another value), just change the fieldset according to the option he chose

```
switch($value) {

                case 'fix':
                    //reset divs 
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset').eq(1).find('div').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('editShow').addClass('hidden');});
                    // fill the time selecting - first clear previous data
                    $('#eminutes, #ehours').empty();
                    for(i=0; i<=59;i++){
                        var append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#eminutes').append(append);
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<=23;i++){
                        append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#ehours').append(append);
                    }
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').eq(0).removeClass('hidden').find('label').text('שעה:');
                break;

                case 'rel':
                    //reset divs 
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset').eq(1).find('div').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('editShow').addClass('hidden');});
                    // fill the time selecting - first clear previous data
                    $('#eminutes, #ehours').empty();
                    for(i=0; i<=59;i++){
                        var append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#eminutes').append(append);
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<=12;i++){
                        append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#ehours').append(append);
                    }
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').eq(0).find('label').text('זמן:');
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                break;
            }

        }

        

    });


    return false;
});
```

When I change from the initial value, I'm creating a clone of the preloaded fieldset with all of it's data. I want that whenever I change back to the initial value, the cloned fieldset will be inserted back. That's what the code actually does, but for some odd reason, it works for the first time, after 1 change, the global var `window.origin_dynamic_fieldset` decides to change it's own value and now hold another fieldset (The other fieldset is the result of changing the option which results in changing fieldset).

## For convenience, here is the whole code at one part:

```
    $('body').on('change','#efixRel', function() {
        
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if(first) {
            dynamic_fieldset = $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset:last-child').clone(true,true);
            first = false;
        }

        if(origin_fixRel == $value) {
            form.find('fieldset').eq(1).remove();
            form.find('.formContainer').eq(0).append(dynamic_fieldset);
        } else {

            switch($value) {

                case 'fix':
                    //reset divs 
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset').eq(1).find('div').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('editShow').addClass('hidden');});
                    // fill the time selecting - first clear previous data
                    $('#eminutes, #ehours').empty();
                    for(i=0; i<=59;i++){
                        var append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#eminutes').append(append);
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<=23;i++){
                        append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#ehours').append(append);
                    }
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').eq(0).removeClass('hidden').find('label').text('שעה:');
                break;

                case 'rel':
                    //reset divs 
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer fieldset').eq(1).find('div').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('editShow').addClass('hidden');});
                    // fill the time selecting - first clear previous data
                    $('#eminutes, #ehours').empty();
                    for(i=0; i<=59;i++){
                        var append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#eminutes').append(append);
                    }
                    for(i=0; i<=12;i++){
                        append = i<10 ? "0"+i : i;
                        append = '<option>'+append+'</option>';
                        $('#ehours').append(append);
                    }
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').eq(0).find('label').text('זמן:');
                    $('#editRecordForm .formContainer .hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                break;
            }

        }

        

    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: this is really bad coding style. it's almost impossible to tell where things go wrong with all your global variables. look at you for-loops for example, your counter is global too, so anything can happen. don't ever use global variables like that. they are considered bad in almost every language that have them that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = $(this).val();
```

Your are setting `window.$value = $value` here, thus it accessible in the global scope in ALL functions. You need to declare variables with the var keyword in order to prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The var `$value` is a var that changes everytime the user change an option, tested it, and the var has no problem it holds the right value everytime. My problem is with `window.dynamic_fieldset` which decides to change it self after changing an option, a thing it shouldn't do

Comment: Edited my code using vars and not using window.varname anymore. Please take a look

Comment: Show the HTML in a JS fiddle.

Comment: When I get back home I will post the HTML as-well

Comment: here is the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/jKU9h/. I'm terribly sorry it's not that neat. The code is generated using PHP so it's kind of messy. However, it's still readable.